# How can I distinguish the short sounds [​ɪ] and [e]?

Tags: pronunciation, vowel

The sound [​ɪ] is said to be more open than [i] and so is [e]. I have no difficulty in distinguishing between [i] and [e], or between [i] and [I]; however, I can hardly distinguish between [​ɪ] and [e] when both appear as short vowels, such as represented by the letter *I* in *ich* and letter *E* in *Mechanik*. To me, they sound too alike in words. Could anyone help with this?

Comment: I in ich and E in Mechanik sound very different. What's the question exactly?

Comment: @Em1 : as [I] in ich and [e:] in sehen ; let us leave out the difference in length between the sounds from consideration temporarily, don't you think the two sounds sound very similar?

Comment: Yes, I do think these sounds are distinguishable. You should even hear a clear difference between E and I in "M**e**chan**i**k".

Comment: Wow, telling someone that he *should* hear something is really helpful.

Comment: @em1: whether one can distinguish two sounds depends very much on what your mother tongue is, so I think this is far from an unclear question and I vote to reopen.

Comment: @Gerhard: So what is the answer, in your opinion? “No, nobody can help you with this”?

Comment: @chirlu: possibly, but that does not mean that it is not a valid question. From all the languages I've learned, it usually comes with time and practice, and there are a surely a few techniques used by language teachers, but that is out of my area of expertise.

Comment: @Gerhard: If that is the question (which I’m not sure of, that’s why this was closed as _unclear_), it’s out of scope here. There is Language Learning SE, though.

Comment: Michanek doesn't sound all too different, though.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, facing such an unknown context, there is no possible way to help.

Comment: @c.p.: just a thought: just because you and I do not have a good answer to the OP's question, this does not necessarily mean that there is not someone out there who does.  After all, this is one of the reasons to ask online.

Comment: @Gerhard That's true, but I happen just not to see the question. Again, what sort of answer would you expect? Don't you think the OP might have said "I speak Chinese / Dutch / Spanish / whatever" as background? I think the OP can always edit, if she wishes her question to be reopened, in case it gets closed.

Comment: @c.p.: so why not be constructive instead and ask the OP to add his/her mother tongue, if you think it is relevant?

Comment: [Related](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/20035/15318). [Also related](http://german.stackexchange.com/q/7872/15318)

Comment: @Close voters: **Please note that the post is not a duplicate. The proposed duplicate is asking for a different hearing issue (the pronunciation of the *letters*)!**

Comment: Cf. also artifically shortened [eː] and artificially lengthened [ɪ] in [Pronunciation of short German ü](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/18375/pronunciation-of-short-german-%C3%BC/52496#52496).

Answer (score 9):

As you correctly say, both [​ɪ] and [e] are more open than [i]. However, [e] is even more open (so the order, starting from the least open, is [i] – [​ɪ] – [e]), and there is another difference: While [i] and [e] are both front vowels, [​ɪ] is produced a bit further back (“near-front”). You can best compare the different positions of all vowels on a [vowel chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Phonetic_Alphabet#Vowels).

[image: IPA vowel chart from Wikimedia Commons]

Native German speakers will usually be able to distinguish between [ɪ] and [e] as the difference is in principle phonemic, although the two sounds rarely appear in opposition (mostly due to short [e] being quite rare by itself). If you can’t distinguish them but want to be able to, there is only one way for you: You need to *train* to hear the difference.

Comment: In terms of *training* your ear, a good approach is to find a few pairs of words that differ **only** in terms of the two vowels that you want to learn. Then have a native speaker repeat the pairs of words until you begin to hear the difference. I have done this many times helping native Mandarin speakers to distinguish various consonants in English (for example by repeating "buck", "bug" ... "buck", "bug" )

Answer (score 4):

[e] appearing as a short (!) vowel is a very rare case. In standard measures, one would consider the unrounded front vowels of German to be [i:] and [​ɪ], [e:] and [ɛ], [ɛ:] (and [ɛ]) and technically also [a:] and [a]; always grouped into pairs of the long and short vowels. These are represented by the letters *i*, *e*, *ä* and *a* and their variants, respectively. (Note that the distinction between long *e* and long *ä*, i.e. [e:] and [ɛ:] is gradually losing its phonemic status; the two are slowly being used interchangeably even though minimal pairs such as *Ehre/Ähre* exist.)

It is of strong phonemic importance to distinguish [i:]/[ɪ] and [e:]/[ɛ], i.e. the two inside each pare: *bitte/biete* and *Beet/Bett* serve as minimal pairs. You should also be able to distinguish between [ɪ]/[ɛ] and [i:]/[e:]; that is also a rather important distinction (*bette/bitte* and *biete/bete*). But those for corners of a rectangle are rather far apart, and vowel length helps in the [i:]/[ɪ] and [ɪ]/[e:] cases.

Short [e] only appears in unstressed, unreduced syllables, meaning that there is another (stressed) syllable that you can use to recognise words. Take the following cases (stress marked with an acute accent):

- *Mechánik.* **Michanik* does not exist and only in rare cases could I imagine a sentence where ambiguity to *mích* (although that is stressed) is possible.
- *lebéndig.* Again, the same thing. **Libéndig* does not exist. I can actually think of a possible way to have those sounds follow each other across word boundaries, but it is too extreme, so I won’t repeat it.

Much more commonly, unstressed (short) *e* is reduced to the shwa [ə] as is almost always the case with the prefix *ge-*.

So all things considered, distinguishing between short [e] and short [ɪ] is not much of an issue.

---

And finally, note that *Mechanik* does not *have* to be pronounced with [e]; I (being from the South) say /mɛ'xanɪk/.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what your native language is. But since you asked in English, I give you some English examples (and of course German examples):

### [​ɪ]

This is the "*near-close near-front unrounded vowel*", or "*near-high near-front unrounded vowel*". You find it in this Englisch words:

- b**i**t [b**ɪ**t]
- **i**nk [**ɪ**ŋk]

It is in this German words:

- b**i**tte [ˈb**ɪ**tə]
- M**i**tte [ˈm**ɪ**tɘ]

### [i]

"*close front unrounded vowel*", or "*high front unrounded vowel*"

English:

- b**ea**t [b**iː**t]
- happ**y** ['hæp**i**]

German:

- M**i**ne [ˈm**iː**nɘ]
- **I**d**i**ot [**i**ˈdi̯oːt]

### [e]

"*close-mid front unrounded vowel*", or "*high-mid front unrounded vowel*"

English:

In English this vowel is very rare. You find it only in the pronunciation of Australian English and in some diphthongs:

- bed [b**e**d] (only australian english)
- hate /h**e**ɪt/

German:

- S**ee**le [ˈz**eː**lə]
- b**e**ten [ˈb**eː**tən]

---

**addendum**

To a German native speaker, [​ɪ] and [i] sound very similar, like two variations of the same sound. Also ​[e] and [⁠ɛ⁠]​ sound in German ears like two Versions of the same sound. But between [​ɪ/i] and [e/⁠ɛ⁠]​ we hear a big difference. They can't be mixed up in German language.

And so I give you also an description of [⁠ɛ⁠]​:

### [⁠ɛ⁠]​

This is the "*open-mid front unrounded vowel*", or "*low-mid front unrounded vowel*"

In English:

- l**e**t [l**ɛ**t]
- m**e**n [m**ɛ**n]

In German:

- n**e**tt [n**ɛ**t]
- H**ä**lfte [ˈh**ɛ**lftʰə]

If you have problems with [e], try to speak it as [⁠ɛ⁠]​. [e] is half way between [i] and [⁠ɛ⁠]​.

Comment: thanks, my difficulty is with [e] ; I am no native speaker of English; I learned 'bed' as [bɛd], which is different from the Australian accent; I learned the diphthong [ei] as an integral glide rather than a juxtaposition of [e] and [i] and this is why I cannot isolate the [e] sound from the diphthong [ei]; besides, I think [e] is pronounced in English more open than in German  : the German [e] is closer to [i] while the English to [ɛ] ?

Comment: @Lynnyo: What is your native language?

Comment: my native language is Mandarin Chinese; I didn't expect any one here would explain the difference between [e] and [I] in terms of Chinese phonology ...

Comment: @Lynnyo: [​i] is in “七”. ​[​ɪ] is in “冰”. [e] is the first vowel in “鼻”. [ɛ] is in “蛇”. And here are some links to chinese descriptions: https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/閉前不圓唇元音 and https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/次閉次前不圓唇元音 and https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/半閉前不圓唇元音 and  https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/半開前不圓唇元音.

Answer (score 0):

German [eː] and [ɪ] are very similar to each other in vowel quality. They mainly differ in vowel quantity. Consequently, when [eː] is shortened to [e] in an unstressed syllable, its pronunciation is virtually identical to [ɪ]. As chirlu has explained, this does not pose any problems since it is in stressed syllables where the two vowels are distinct. They seldom occur in unstressed syllables, and I do not believe there are any minimal pairs. Furthermore, as Jan has said, unstressed [eː] may be opened to [ɛ].

The similarity of German [eː] and [ɪ] can be demonstrated by taking recordings of words with [eː] and [ɪ] and artificially lengthening or shortening them (e.g. with [Praat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Praat)).

- *[Sehne](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/78/De-Sehne.ogg)* ~ [artificially lengthened *Sinne*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6f/De-Sinne.lengthened.ogg)
- *[Sinne](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/22/De-Sinne.ogg)* ~ [artificially shortened *Sehne*](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/De-Sehne.shortened.ogg)

Answer (score -4):

Just as in English, the difference is much more audible in stressed syllables than in unstressed ones. Don't listen to "Mechanik" to get an idea of [e]; listen to "Messer" instead.

Comment: Messer is yet another pronunciation, namely /ɛ/, often similar or identical to "ä", which is yet another letter. How is this useful?

Comment: @Em1 Not for me, and apparently not for Lynnyo either.

Comment: @KilianFoth If you use the same first vowel in *Messer* and *Mechanik*, do you use /ɛ/ for both or /e/ for both? (The second looks unlikely to me.) Is the first vowel in *Messer* and *Mechanik* the short version of the vowel in *Schnee*, or is it different?

Comment: @Uwe (...looks up IPA table...) I use /ɛ/ for both. I had no idea this would be controversial. As far as I can tell, this *is* the 'short' version of *Schnee*, but I seem to remember that 'short' isn't really a a proper linguistic term.

Comment: @KilianFoth No, the standard High German pronounciation has /e:/ in "Schnee", /ɛ:/ in "Ähre", /e/ in "lebendig" or "Mechanik", and /ɛ/ in "Messer" or "nässer". Dialects differ, though (e.g., Swabian).

Comment: /meˈçaːnɪk/ and /mɛçˈaːnɪk/ both sound normal to me and my actual pronunciation depends a bit on contextual words, e.g. _Mechanikvorlesung_ /e/ vs. _Technische Mechanik_ /ɛ/. Anyhow, a loan word is often not the best choice to analyze the phonology of a language and this answer is not helpful without the comments.